# A flash game in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am using a jquery plugin "fancybox" to open a flash game.
The game is opened, but when I click a button in the game nothing happens.
What parameters are missing?

```
$("a#play").fancybox({
                    'padding'           : 7,
                    'type': 'swf'

                });
```

UPD: I mean that I can see the game menu and it's animation, but when I press a button in the menu, nothing happens (the game doesn't start). When the game is opened in a regular way (going to a link), everything is fine.

UPD2:
I receive error: "GET http://myhost/crossdomain.xml 404"

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Could you make a demo to show us the problem?

Comment: added an update to the question

Comment: Do you need any additional flash params, like wmmode? An online demo would help very much. Also, does the file crossdomain.xml exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like you have to create a crossdomain policy file for your domain.

Here you can find why and how.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html